# Python 2.7 Program not working in MAC terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal

I am teaching an intro to coding class for students and we are attempting to run the following program. It is giving a syntax error. Here are both the program and error message:

```
# Introduction
print 'Hello. If you give me your scores, I can find your overall grade.'
ques = raw_input('Would you like me to find your class grade? y/n ')


# Get first score
if ques in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes']:
    count = 1
    sum = int(raw_input('What is your first score? ')
    ans = raw_input('Do you have another score for me? y/n ')
else:
    ans = 'no'
    print 'Thanks anyway. Run me later if you change your mind.'

# Get other scores
while ans in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes']:
    sum = sum + int(raw_input('What is the next score? ')
    count = count + 1
    ans = raw_input('Do you have another score for me? y/n ')

# Calculate score
avg = sum / count
print 'Your class grade is:', avg
```

Error message:

```
Last login: Wed Jun 18 10:07:31 on ttys000
D-iMac-00:~ prog$ /var/folders/1r/zxdwc24s2h5gncz_q09x46rw0000gq/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/fancy_grade-424798099.021.py.command ; exit;
  File "/Users/prog/Desktop/Jake/fancy_grade.py", line 10
    ans = raw_input('Do you have another score for me? y/n ')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on a preceding line:

```
sum = int(raw_input('What is the next score? ')
#        ^         ^                          ^^ ?
#        |          \-------- matched -------/ |
#         \-------------- missing --------------/
```

You do so again later on in the program:

```
sum = sum + int(raw_input('What is the next score? ')
#              ^         ^                          ^^ ?
#              |          \-------- matched -------/ |
#              \-------------- missing --------------/
```

You may want to take a look at [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for tips on how to handle user input better.

Comment: Perfect. I copied and pasted without looking carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ")" on line 9. Syntax errors are usually related to things like that.